# document.getElementsByClassName e elementos com mais de uma classe

Tags: javascript

Quando um elemento tem mais de uma classe funciona se usar `document.getElementsByClassName` passando apenas uma das classes?

Se eu tiver um elemento como:

```
<div class="class1 class2 class3 ..."></div>
```

Eu posso pegar esse elemento dessa forma?

```
document.getElementByClassname("class1")[i];
```

E se eu fizer `element.className = "class";` isso vai apagar todas as classes que esse elemento tinha ou vai adicionar uma?

E para adicionar é usando `+=`, correto?

Comment: funciona sim...

Comment: E se eu fizer element.className = "class"; isso vai apagar todas as classes que esse elemento tinha ou vai adicionar uma?

Comment: Vai substituir tudo. mas se quiser adicionar tem como.

Comment: pra adicionar é usando += né?

Comment: isso mesmo, recomendo usar esse site https://fiddle.jshell.net/, é ótimo para fazer testes simples desse tipo

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção, ajudou muito mesmo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `getElementbyclassname` vai buscar todos os elementos que tenham uma dada classe e retorna uma coleção de elementos. Detalhes importantes:

- o método retorna uma coleção, e não uma array.

Para ter uma array tem de se converter com:

```
var arr = [].slice.call(colecao); // compativel com JavaScript antigo
var arr = Array.from(colecao); // ES5 (não suportado no IE)
var arr = [...colecao]; // ES6
```

- repara que `getElementbyclassname` tem `E` grande (na pergunta tinhas `e` pequeno)
- mesmo que um elemento tenha mais/outras classes ele vai buscar esse elemento desde que tenha a classe que está à procura

---

Para adicionar uma classe a um elemento pode usar-se o `.className = ...` mas é preciso ter em conta que as classes são separadas por espaços. Então `el.className += 'nova-classe'` vai efeito indesejado pois vai colar com a classe antiga, tem de ser `+= ' nova-classe'` (repara no espaço `' nova-...`.

Porem a melhor maneira é usar o novo método de ES5, a [API `.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).

Para:

- adicionar: `el.classList.add('nova-classe', 'mais-outra', etc...)`
- remover: `el.classList.remove('minha-classe')`